# Laravel giving timeout errors on 2 millions records

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

We are using Laravel eloquent to fetch data from the database. Our Table has more than 2 million rows. Fetching this data with ajax and also paginated
Now it starts giving a timeout error. Here is the query

```
 $histories = History::query();
 $histories->where('model', $strtable)->where('object_id', $po_id);
 $histories->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

Most probably indexing will solve this issue may be. Please correct me if I am wrong.
One column is string type where I am using where clause may I need to use full-text indexing there?

But my real concern is how long indexing can help out this issue? what if records reach 4 million?
Because in our system thousands of records are being inserted on daily basis and that is a concern for us.

Please guide

Comment: what is the errors? I think you need to upgrade server limit or upgrade your server or at least using queue.

Comment: add `select()` statement and select those are nesseasy and `model` and `object_id` make it index as your query based on that and try to use laravel chunk system https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: Please add your database schema

Comment: "Most probably indexing will solve this issue may be." It sure will! Check your database system documentation on indexes. I wouldn't worry too much about 4 million records and indexes. Yes, your database size will grow, but with a correct index your data will be optimised.